# clickhouse table ttl does not work in version 21.8.4.51

Tags: clickhouse, ttl

I use spark streaming to consume records from kafka and write them to clickhouse table with ttl, the clickhouse version is 21.8.4.51, and my table ddl is as follow:

```
CREATE TABLE dataplugin.ods_stb_boot_up_delay_all_local ON CLUSTER '{cluster}'(
`evtTime` Int64,
`evtCode` String,
`pVer` String,
`stbID` String,
`bootUpDelay` Int64,
`provinceCode` String,
`writeTime` DateTime,
INDEX pattern_match stbID TYPE ngrambf_v1(3,256,2,0) GRANULARITY 3
)
ENGINE=ReplicatedMergeTree('/clickhouse/ods_stb_boot_up_delay_all_local/{shard}','{replica}') 
PARTITION BY toYYYYMMDD(writeTime) 
ORDER BY (stbID,evtTime) 
TTL writeTime + INTERVAL 3 MONTH 
SETTINGS 
merge_with_ttl_timeout = 86400,
index_granularity = 8192,
use_minimalistic_part_header_in_zookeeper=1
```

However, on Nov 30, 2022 I can still get the result from my query:

```
# Query:
select count(1) from dataplugin.ods_stb_boot_up_delay_all_local where writeTime <= '2022-07-01 00:00:00';
# Result:
_____count()______
|   37323403     |
|________________|
```

the field of the table called 'writeTime' means the date time that a record is put into the table, theoretically, the query result should be 0, I tried `ALTER table #{tableName} MATERIALIZE TLL`, `OPTIMIZE TABLE #{tableName} ON '{cluster}' FINAL`, `system start TTL MERGES`, none of them works,  so I really need your help, and so many data in table cause lots of znodes in zookeeper's replica nodes, it may result in failure in restart of clickhouse server

Answer (score 0):

Was the TTL rule defined during creation of the table or did you update the table and created the TTL afterwards?

FWIW, is there a specific reason partitioning the table by toYYYYMMDD(writeTime)? Not only does that lower query performance, because you have more parts, i.e. more files that have to be read, you could also benefit from the DROP PARTITION feature.

Either keep the partition by day, and simply drop the daily partitions, or repartition the table to a monthly partition and drop monthly partitions as a whole.

You would need to do that either manually, or better, with a cronjob or similar.

One more downside of TTL merges is that they can be very, and I mean it, very expensive in terms of cpu and i/o resource usage, depending on the partition key design and the size of the parts in the partition. If possible, one should prefer dropping partitions over the TTL feature.

For some reading: https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/faq/operations/delete-old-data/#drop-partition

Comment: Thanks for your answer, @Richard Steinbrecht, after lots of experiments on my clickhouse cluster with 6 nodes, I thinks I finally get the reason why my clickhouse table ttl does not work. the reason is that the CPU of two nodes in my clickhouse cluster are overloaded, which are up to 200%, so the backgroud thread may be always in pending list in the case of lack of  working resources

Comment: Great that you found the reason. I suspect the CPU is overloaded due to the TTL merges? Or is it for another reason?